# How do I secure the Jenkins github-webhook path?

Tags: security, authentication, github, jenkins, webhooks

I started to set up GitHub webhooks with Jenkins, and I got it working as https://jenkins.mydomain.com/github-webhook/ - without the username and password. I want to secure it with a username and password (or some other means, if there's a better/more commonly used auth method for this), but before that I want to make sure that this unauthenticated webhook URL access is not publicly accessible.

I'm using Jenkins 2.5 with the github-plugin version 1.19.1. Global security is set to use the built-in Active Directory feature, and anonymous users don't have any access. Anonymous access to project and root jenkins paths always forward to the login page, yet this path is unsecured. My Jenkins server is behind an apache2 reverse-proxy.

Comment: are you using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin?

Comment: yes, that's the github plugin i'm currently using